# Using Socket I/O client in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sockets

HI i'm new to using socket I/O.

I would like to use the socket send and receive functions in multiple screens like a chat app. I'm not understanding how to handle it. can anyone help me.

I'm using the socket from https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift

I'm using objective-c coding

Comment: Your question appears to be  very vague: teach me about sockets. My personal suggestion would be to understand what sockets are and how they work on a low level. I like the classic Beej's Guide to Network Programming: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My dear friend,

*Links below are links I've read when I developed iOS Chat Client using Socket.io recently,*

If you're a project based learner, you can see full working **iOS Chat Client Using Socket.io** sample here: https://github.com/bonnguyen/socket.io_chat_swift

Just try to build and run it. It helps me a lot, but unfortunately it's written in Swift. Hope you can translate it to Obj-C by yourself.

**Bonus:**

*for your information*, for chat view, you can use this library: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController

or if you like to create your own code for chat view, you can read this tutorial:
http://www.innofied.com/creating-old-style-message-bubble-swift/